# How to return a struct?

Tags: c

I am having difficulty defining the return type in the method signature properly.  The problem is 
`list* GetPrimeNumbers()`

```
struct dynamicArray{
   int val;
   struct dynamicArray * next;
};

typedef struct dynamicArray list;

int PrimeFactor()
{
    int sum = 0;
    list * primeNumbers;
    primeNumbers = GetPrimeNumbers();
    return sum;
}

list* GetPrimeNumbers()
{
    int max = 100;

    list * current, * head;
    head = NULL;

    for(int i = 2; i < max; i++)
    {
     //..implmenetation
    }    
    return current;
}
```

I have tried several return types, but nothing has worked.  I am a beginner level C programmer.  What needs to be there?

Comment: A dynamic array and a linked list are two totally different things.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with the code you posted (`current` is of type `list*`). Something might be wrong in the implementation part. What is the error message BTW ?

Comment: What do you mean by "hasn't worked"? What goes wrong?

Comment: kind of hard for us to help when you left out the bit of code that actually assigned to current!

Comment: Seems to make a lot more sense for GetPrimeNumbers to return `head` rather than `current`. Of course that depends on the implementation which you left out. Also, `PrimeFactor()` will always return 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you need a header file with the `typedef` and prototype for `GetPrimeNumbers`, or you need to swap the functions `GetPrimeNumbers` and `PrimeFactor` in the file.

The way you presented the code, `GetPrimeNumbers` has no declaration in place when `PrimeFactor` is compiled.

Comment: +1 - Yep, swapping the order fixed it.  Going to take some getting used to this language, haven't used it in years.